# Product of two different conditional probabilities in sequences?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Imagine I am looking for the conditional probability of a sequence which I determine recursively by multiplication of incremental probabilities, each based upon the previous, let's say:

$$p(x_{1:n}|C)=p(x_1|C)\prod_{i = 2}^n p(x_i|x_{1:i-1},C)$$

where $C$ is a constant parameter and $x_{1:n}=x_1,x_2,...x_n$.

Now my question: *Is it possible to change the parameter $C$ in the middle of the sequence? If so, what analytic form would the resulting probability distribution have?*

I propose the following solution, without knowing if such a solution would even be valid/correct:

$$p(x_{1:n}|C_1,C_2)=p(x_1|C_1)\prod_{i = 2}^5 p(x_i|x_{1:i-1},C_1)\prod_{i = 6}^n p(x_i|x_{1:5},C_1,x_{5:i-1},C_2)$$

with $n>5$. Here I assume that the parameter $C$ changes at the 6th position in the sequence, but the incremental probability is still dependent on its trajectory of previous values, which were conditional on $C_1$.

*Is this correct? If so, can I write it like this?*